# Convert Oracle query to SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

I have been trying to convert Oracle query to SQLAlchemy specifically ORM
Here is the SQL I want to convert:

```
SELECT p.id,
    p.name,
    p.address,
    to_char(t.s_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') date_s,
    t.date_h,
FROM p_table p,
    (SELECT t_id,
           dept,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t_id ORDER BY dept) AS row_id
      FROM t_table
     WHERE t_id = :t_id
       AND actual_time IS NULL) t

WHERE p.id = :id_var
AND row_id = 1
ORDER BY date_c DESC
```

Here is my attempt on converting this:

```
 row_id = func.row_number().over(partition_by=TModel.t_id, order_by=TModel.dept)
 sub_query = db.session.query(TModel.t_id, TModel.dept)\
                             .add_column(row_id)\
                             .from_self().filter(row_id == 1)\
                             .filter(TModel.t_id == t_id)\
                             .filter(TModel.actual_time == None)\
                             .label("sub_query")

  q = db.session.query(PModel.id, PModel.name,
                 PModel.address, TModel.s_time, TModel.temp, sub_query)\
                      .filter(PModel.t_id == t_id)\
                      .order_by(PModel.date_complete.desc())\
                      .all()

  print q
```

Actual error is that it returns more than it is expecting for example running the SQL in pl/sql returns 5 while using SQLAlchemy is returning more than 5. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Check your queries carefully; the translation is designed to be very straightforward. A good way to check is to get the compiled SQL from your `Query` object and then check it against the original SQL that you want to produce. Here are some problems I could spot: 1. your `row_id = 1` condition appears in the outer query in your SQL, but it's in the subquery in your SQLAlchemy expression; 2. your outer query has the condition `p.id = :id_var` in your SQL, but it has the condition `t_id = :t_id` in your SQLAlchemy expression.

Comment: Yeah, I have messed the condition in problem #2. For problem #1, I am not sure how could I call the column in the subquery to the outer query?

Comment: Your `row_id` needs a label (`func.row_number()....label("row_id")`), then you could filter on it in the outer query using `sub_query.c.row_id == 1`.